# Pandas: Merge dataframe and series based on index

Tags: python, pandas

I created following dataframe `priceearning_byyear`, which is still incomplete:

[image]

Afterwards, I would like to "insert"/merge following series `price` into the above df:

[image]

The serie has one row (2021) too much, which I would like to remove when inserting into the above df.

My attempt is:

```
priceearning_byyear.merge(price.to_frame(), left_index=True)
```

But I got following error:

```
MergeError: Must pass right_on or right_index=True
```

If I use `right_index=True`, I'll get :

```
MergeError: Must pass left_on or left_index=True
```

I don't get it, why it doesn't work. Thank you for any pointer:-)

Comment: this post may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/23660378/13273054

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. Just pass `left_index` and `right_index` simultaneously to get the desired effect as below.

```
# Reproduce your data
import pandas as pd
priceearning_byyear = pd.DataFrame(dict(year=[2016,2017,2018,2019,2020], eps=[2.09,2.32,3.00,2.99,3.31])).set_index('year')
price = pd.Series([28.95,42.31,39.44,73.41,132.69,119.99], index=[2016,2017,2018,2019,2020,2021])
price.name = 'Close'
price.index.name='year'

# Merge priceearning_byyear and price by using their indexes
priceearning_byyear.merge(price,left_index=True,right_index=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the column which you want to merge on in `priceearning_byyear`.

```
data1 = {"year":[x for x in range(2016, 2020)], "eps":[x for x in range(2,12,2)]}
data2 = pd.Series(data = {2016: 1, 2017: 2, 2018: 3, 2019: 4, 2020: 5, 2021: 6})

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df1.merge(data2.to_frame(name='price'), how='left', left_on="year", right_index=True)
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4o03K.png)

Answer (score 0):

Another example I run into recently. The index of my dataframe was datetime, and my series was integers. What I did was write a small function to merge the dataframe and series for me in the following steps:

- first, by converting to the series to a dataframe, and setting its index using the dataframe's index, and
- second, merging the two dataframes and renaming the series' column.

**Note**: The function assumes that the dataframe and series have the same length.

```
def merge_df_series(x, y):
    """
    Merge dataframe and series on index
    and rename series column.
    """
    series = y.to_frame().set_index(x.index)
    return x.merge(series, left_index=True, right_index=True).rename(columns={0: 'y'})
```